# Android build fails on Sonar step with no output error

Tags: android, jenkins, sonarqube, build.gradle

**Edit**: Simplifying and summarizing all:

- I have to make a Jenkins job work, it uses `build.gradle` file. I did not take part in dev process;
- **there is no connectivity issues** (other projects on the same node are posting to sonar server);
- sonar step is configured, but improperly used.

---

Gradle is used for building. There is a Sonar step which is failing.

The error is a bit strange:

```
Task 'app:sonar' is not up-to-date because:
Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
...
SonarQube server [<server url>] can not be reached
```

There are 2 build.gradle files. One in the top level directory:

```
buildscript {
   ...
   repositories { ... }
   dependencies { ... }
   allprojects {
      repositories { ... }
   }
}
task clean(type: Delete) { ... }
```

And there is one in the project directory:

```
plugins {
   id 'org.sonarqube' version '4.4.1.3373'
   ...
}
sonarqube {
   properties {
      property "sonar.host.url", "server"
      property "sonar.projectKey", "key"
      property "sonar.login", "token"
   }
}
android {
   buildTypes { ... }
   productFlavors { ... }
}
dependencies { ... }
```

As far as I understood Gradle runs the 'sonarqube' as a step and there should be output to be sent to the server, but currently there is none.

Any suggestions what could be missing?

Comment: Does it work locally? `SonarQube server [<server url>] can not be reached` doesn't seem to relate to Gradle configuration.

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev I'm on the ops side of this project, and I don't have a working knowledge of Android. With --info flag there is more in the error message. I've updated the question.

Comment: it doesn't seem to relate to Android either, I'm just suggesting to run the same command as Jenkins runs as the first step of troubleshooting. [`--info`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html#sec:choosing_a_log_level) flag just controls the logging level of Gradle, so the message you're referring to seems to be just an info-level message. The real issue according to your log is that the build wasn't able to connect to Sonar server API.

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev I have other jobs on the same node and they have access to the sonar server. Connectivity is no issue. There was no sonar in the gradle file originally. I've added it, and I think not in a correct way.

Comment: `There was no sonar in the gradle file originally. I've added it,` I think you should commit the gradle file modifications to your version control and try it again. In a CI/CD flow, the first step is that checkout your code from VCS.

Comment: @Bakudan Are there typos in the question? Shouldn't there be commas between the property names and values in the sonarqube plugin configuration? Like `property "sonar.host.url", "server"` instead of `property "sonar.host.url" "server"`

Comment: @devatherock yes you are right, there are commas. I fixed them in the question.

Comment: Double-check the sonar server is reachable with the same domain name, port and protocol before running sonarqube.

Comment: @hakre literally the 3 line. I have other jobs on the same node which are working as expected.

Comment: then revert the configuration back to the last known good. _literally_.

Comment: @hakre I have to make the gradle file work, to make the jenkins job succeed. Revert the configuration is to remove sonar from gradle... Which is kind of the opposite of what I asked for help.

Comment: @Bakudan did you compare a working project with the failing one? Is Sonar server URL and all other connection properties the same for all of them? Are the projects getting built in the same environment? Do their Jenkinsfiles differ? I understood your answer to my initial question on the local run as you're unable to check it locally, but unfortunately you didn't provide enough other data either. I'm afraid any suggestions would be no more than guesses at the current point.

Comment: @Bakudan: Yes, but again more the way _Alexander Pletnev_ was reading it. If you think it's the known working good, double-check it actually is. Because as you describe, it is not working (towards your favour).

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78120218/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar) plagiariser. For instance, check the perfect spelling and grammar in the answer and the close to incomprehensible first comment.

Comment: @PeterMortensen usually the questions like this get flagged requesting for additional details. Since the question has a bounty, it cannot be flagged, thus no one else tries to answer it.